Laurent series $f(z) =\frac{(2z-2)}{(z^2-3z+2)}$ around $0<|z-2|<1$
I've used Trinom to find roots and got
$f(z) =\frac{2(z-1)}{(z-1)(z-2)}$.
And for some reason I cannot remember if it would be legal to do away with the $\frac{(z-1)}{(z-1)}$ to be left with
$f(z) =\frac{2}{(z-2)}$ .
I'm not sure if that would be ok? Its been a while since I dabbled in series and expansions.
Help?

If $0<|z-2|<1$ then $z\neq 1$, so in that annulus $$f(z)=\dfrac{2(z-1)}{(z-1)(z-2)}=\dfrac{2}{z-2},$$
which is already expressed as a power series in terms of $z-2$, and consequently is the Laurent series of $f$ in $0<|z-2|<1$.

So the seires would be $2*sigma{(z-2)^n}$  ?

No, the series is simply $\dfrac{2}{z-2}$. In this case we only have a term in the whole series.

I see! thank you!
